# Python tkinter text frame function text

Tags: python, tkinter

Good evening how can print in text frame, function def print? it must be type in text frame "ffedede"
[image]

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

def goster():
    print("ffedede")

root = tk.Tk()

root.geometry("729x506+299+135")
Ana_cerceve = ttk.Frame(root)
Ana_cerceve.place(relx=0.014, rely=0.02, relheight=0.943
        , relwidth=0.97)
Text1 = tk.Text(Ana_cerceve)
Text1.place(relx=0.04, rely=0.048, relheight=0.843, relwidth=0.903
       , bordermode='ignore')
Text1.insert(tk.END, goster) ????????????

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`print` function writes string to terminal. It can't be displayed in Tinker.

You should write:

```py
import sys
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

def goster():
    return "ffedede" # it's return 'ffedede'

root = tk.Tk()

root.geometry("729x506+299+135")
Ana_cerceve = ttk.Frame(root)
Ana_cerceve.place(relx=0.014, rely=0.02, relheight=0.943
        , relwidth=0.97)
Text1 = tk.Text(Ana_cerceve)
Text1.place(relx=0.04, rely=0.048, relheight=0.843, relwidth=0.903
       , bordermode='ignore')
Text1.insert(tk.END, goster()) # it must be called to get return value (ffedede)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think ı try this by the way thanks

Comment: Your first statement is false. It's possible to have `print` send its data to a text widget.